# Retrieving error while saving image in bitmap from image picker in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using Photopicker Library [Link](https://github.com/dbotha/Android-Photo-Picker) to retrive the collection of Images from SD Card. I need to save those images into the  bitmap so i can pass it to the another class (this class only accepts the Bitmaps [Link](https://github.com/azki/Animated-gif-Encoder-For-Android)).

In below code i am retrieving the collection of images that was chosen from the Image Picker.

```
public byte[] generateGIF(Photo[] collection) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
    Bitmap[] allimages = null ; **// Array of Bitmap images**
    int i=0;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    encoder.start(bos);
    for (Photo photo : collection) {
        Log.i("After", "URI: " + photo.getUri());

   //Photo[] is a array of Photo class that holds the array of the images selected via Image Picker.
  // getUri() is a method in Photo class to retrieve the Uri of the Image.
        allimages[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.getUri().getPath(),options);

        i++;
        encoder.addFrame(allimages[i]);
    }
    i=0;
    encoder.finish();
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

When execute i am getting below error.
**Retrieving the error "BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/45 (No such file or directory)"**

I have also tried below solutions but that doesn't work either.

```
 //allimages[i] = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),photo.getUri());
```

And have tried below too

```
  // allimages[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.getUri().getPath());
```

Please help me with this.
thanks in advance...

Error log after :Log.i("After", "URI: " + photo.getUri());

03-27 21:16:12.624 2393-2393/com.patel.pritesh.myapplication I/After: URI: content://media/external/images/media/44
03-27 21:16:12.624 2393-2393/com.patel.pritesh.myapplication I/Okay: URI: content://media/external/images/media/44
03-27 21:16:12.624 2393-2393/com.patel.pritesh.myapplication E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/media/external/images/media/44 (No such file or directory)
03-27 21:16:12.624 2393-2393/com.patel.pritesh.myapplication W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array
03-27 21:16:12.624 2393-2393/com.patel.pritesh.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.patel.pritesh.myapplication.MainActivity.generateGIF(MainActivity.java:184)
03-27 21:16:12.625 2393-2393/com.patel.pritesh.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.patel.pritesh.myapplication.MainActivity.GifCreator(MainActivity.java:155)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to get absolute path from URI. Use the following code to do so:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO_PICKER) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Photo[] photos = PhotoPicker.getResultPhotos(data);
            Toast.makeText(this, "User selected " + photos.length + " photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for (Photo photo : photos) {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getRealPathFromURI(this,photo.getUri()),options);
                Log.i("dbotha", "URI: " + getRealPathFromURI(this, photo.getUri()));
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Photo Picking Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Log.i("dbotha", "Unknown result code: " + resultCode);
        }
    }
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Implement getRealPathFromURI() method in your app like above that returns the path. Use this path in bitmap factory. I have checked there is no crash for me in the above code. Hope it helps :)

Comment: hi @mudit pant  Photo class in the Image Picker Library has only one method. which is getUri(). check [Here] (https://github.com/dbotha/Android-Photo-Picker/blob/master/photopicker/src/main/java/ly/kite/photopicker/Photo.java) I am tryng to get Path using getPath() method . How do i solve this issue.? as i am not able to use getPath() or getAbsolutePath() directly on this.

Comment: Can you post the log statement for Log.i("After", "URI: " + photo.getUri().toString());. Also can you please check whether /external/images/media/ folder is there ? Use adb shell and then cd to that folder

Comment: I have edited my answer. Problem was to get path from URI. It works now.

Comment: Thanks, @mudit pant. This works perfectly fine.. Thank you very much